# QT 5.6 update() function identifier not found

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make a programm, where a function will be drawn on button click. It looks like this (mainwindow.h)

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
~MainWindow();

private slots:
void on_pushButton_clicked();

protected:
 void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event); // This is re-implemented from QWidget
protected slots:
 void draw();
private:
 bool drawTheLines;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
     delete ui;
}

 void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
     if(drawTheLines){
       //draw function here
            }
     QWidget::paintEvent(event);


}
void draw()
   {
      bool drawTheLines = true;
      update();
   }
```

The problem is - compiling fails, and error says "C3861: udpate: Identifier not found"

Comment: where does the `drawTheLines` come from? How should `MainWindow` access it?

Comment: I've added drawTheLines to mainwindow.h

Comment: you also have to add `MainWindow::` in front of `draw` too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to declare MainWindow::draw() in cpp:

```
void MainWindow::draw()
{
    drawTheLines = true;
    update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `update` function is not defined!

Maybe you want to call the `update` function of the QMainWindow, but the function `draw` is not a member function of QMainWindow, so no implicit `this` is here in function `draw`.

There are two ways to solve it, but you should pick the excepted one!

1. Make the `draw` function to be the member function of your class
   `MainWindow`.
2. Make your `draw` function to be like this

   ```
   void draw(QMainWindow *window){  
       bool drawTheLines = true;  
       window->update();  
   }
   ```

But, I think you may want the first solution, cause the drawTheLines variable in function `MainWindow::paintEvent` is not defined yet.